# How do 'virtual kinematics/functions' play a role during deriving weak form formulations for physical problems?

Tags: finite-element, pde, weak-solution

I wanna ask a question that confuses me quite a long time. I saw many guys, in the context of computational mechanics,  they seemed to choose the virtual functions or kinematics in a way that some kinematical quantities are kept/fixed zero, but  they ask the remaining  of  them   to act as roles during the derivation of  a weak form equation. In the end, we can generally get a system of weak equations. I am all the time wondering whether we have a chance to change the nature of the original physical problem of a strong form.  Who can shed lights on my doubts in a physcial or mathematical view?

Edit: 
Say, u=u1+u2+u3 for whatever reason. Its variation is delta u1+ delta u2 +delta u3. The weak form may be integral sigma(u): sym gradient(delta u1) =0, integral sigma(u): sym gradient(delta u2) =0, integral sigma(u): sym gradient(delta u3) =0.

Comment: Ps: We can do whatever we want with maths. However, sometimes I almost lose the physical insights .

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you asking 'why do we use weak formulations'? Or 'Why do we need virtual functions'?

Comment: Neither.For example, u=u1+u2. When formulating the weak form, one can set delta u1=0, but delta u2 arbitrarily, where  delta means variation operation.

Comment: Your clarification seems more confusing to me :S

Comment: Sounds a bit like a decomposition into mean and fluctuation. The mean $u_1$ can be demanded to vanish at the boundary, that would be similar to the Hamiltonian principle. The fluctuations $u_2$ then encode everything that you've forced out of $u_1$ by demanding $\delta u_1=0$.

Comment: Or is it d'Alemberts principle of virtual work you're talking about here? I think this is really more a physics question then..

Comment: @nicoguaro You may probably think of variational multiscale paradigm proposed by Hughes in 1996 if i remember the year correctly, as an example.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Yes. That is what i wanna make clear. A mean field plus fluctuations. Fluctuation information may come from a lower level or scale FEM computations, like in multiscle schemes.

Comment: Can you use MathJax to edit your question please?

Comment: @nicoguaro I will do this later when I am in front of my computer. Sometimes, I use my phone to post or edit wording and I am not sure if i can use mathJax utility.